# Xcode cannot stop a running task

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5

There is a problem when I run a C++ program in Xcode. There is always a session saying `Debug xxx`, but this cannot be stopped. There is no problem with the code.

Some screenshots here:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also experienced this issue, and I have a couple things that may work. Note these are not bug fixes, but workarounds - they may not work in your case. However, I hope they do...

Try in sequential order...

- Click (upper bar) -> Product -> Stop, though you may have tried this.
- Click (upper bar)-> Product -> Clean. This may stop the errant task.
- Quit Xcode and reopen. In my experience, this almost always stops the "running" task.
- Though I haven't needed to get this far, it may help to force quit XCode (command+option+escape) or restart the computer.

To prevent it from happening in the future, be sure to always stop the run before you unplug the phone you are running it on (at least, that's what caused it for me). Stop it by going to (upper bar) -> Product -> Stop.

Comment: The problem is solved after I restart the computer, although I don't know the reason. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This appears to still be the solution 6 years later